# Any reason why this script won't install python-dotenv?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, packer

I'm creating an image using Packer and I was able to get it to install the requests module successfully. However, I also need the dotenv module as well and it's throwing an error when trying to install dotenv in my script. My base image is an Ubuntu 20.04 image

The strange part is, I can create an image with the original script, ssh into my ec2 instance and run "sudo apt-get install -y python3-dotenv" manually and it works fine, but for some reason when I include it in my script it gives me this error:

"Unable to locate package python3-dotenv"

Here's my original packer script that worked (without including dotenv):

```
provisioner "shell" {
inline = ["sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y python3-requests"]
}
```

Then I tried to include the install dotenv command in two seperate ways and they both threw the same error mentioned above

First try

```
provisioner "shell" {
inline = ["sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y python3-requests && sudo apt-get install -y python3-dotenv"]
}
```

Second Try

```
provisioner "shell" {
inline = ["sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y python3-requests", "sudo apt-get install -y python3-dotenv"]
}
```

I even tried to implement a 10 second pause between the first script and second script and it still returned the same error.

I'm a total noob to packer and scripting in general, so I feel like it could be something simple that I just don't comprehend, but it's confusing how I can manually run the dotenv command and it works fine, but including it in my script throws an error for that module only.

My complete packer template:

```
locals {
  timestamp = regex_replace(timestamp(), "[- TZ:]", "")
}

source "amazon-ebs" "ubuntu" {
  ami_name      = "${var.ami_prefix}-${local.timestamp}"
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  region        = var.region
  source_ami_filter {
    filters = {
      name                = "ubuntu/images/*ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"
      root-device-type    = "ebs"
      virtualization-type = "hvm"
    }
    most_recent = true
    owners      = ["099720109477"]
  }
  ssh_username = "ubuntu"
  tags         = var.tags
}

build {
  name = "ubuntu"
  sources = [
    "source.amazon-ebs.ubuntu"
  ]
    provisioner "shell" {
    inline = [
      "echo Installing Updates",
      "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y python3-requests"
    ]
  } 
    provisioner "shell" {
    inline = [
      "sudo apt-get install -y python-dotenv"
    ]
  }
}
```

My first two tries I had it in the same provisioner block and I decided to try it in a second provisioner block and implement a 10s break in between to see if that did anything and I got the same result, so I got rid of the 10s break and ran out of ideas

Comment: What base image are you using? Can you include your complete packer manifest in your question?

Comment: @larsks Will do, I'll update my post, but my base image is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: The package name is `python3-dotenv`, not `python-dotenv`.

Comment: @larsks I originally had that and was getting the same error, so I switched it to python-dotenv just to try every random thing I could think of. I just switched it back to python3-dotenv and got the unable to locate package python3-dotenv error again

Comment: Using your packer script provisioning commands to build a docker image based on `ubuntu:20.04`, I can't reproduce that problem. I'm not able to try the build in AWS.

Comment: @larsks That's strange, I'll keep toying with things and see if I can get it figured out, I really appreciate the help